# How to consume nested rest resource in Angular?

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, httpclient

I am using Angular 5 to do web UI. This web UI uses restful endpoints in a backend service which is written using Java and Spring data rest. This is the endpoints like:

http://localhost:8080/

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "accounts" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/accounts{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "build-and-test-submissions" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/build-and-test-submissions{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "build-submissions" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/build-submissions{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

The `build-and-test-submissions` and `build-submissions` endpoints are of major concern in this project.

http://localhost:8080/build-and-test-submissions

```
    {
  "_embedded" : {
    "build-and-test-submissions" : [ {
      "changeListId" : "23967925",
      "postedAt" : null,
      "lastUpdatedAt" : null,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/build-and-test-submissions/1"
        },
        "buildAndTestSubmission" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/build-and-test-submissions/1"
        },
        "buildSubmission" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/build-and-test-submissions/1/buildSubmission"
        },
        "account" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/build-and-test-submissions/1/account"
        }
      }
    },  ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/build-and-test-submissions{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/build-and-test-submissions"
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/build-and-test-submissions/search"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 5,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

http://localhost:8080/build-submissions

```
   {
      "_embedded" : {
        "build-submissions" : [ {
          "nvBranchName" : "some_branch",
          "nvPackageName" : "some_package",
          "isBuildSubmitted" : false,
          "isBuildCompleted" : false,
          "isTestSubmitted" : false,
          "isTestCompleted" : false,
          "packageLocation" : "",
          "jobId" : -1,
          "_links" : {
            "self" : {
              "href" : "http://localhost:8080/build-submissions/1"
            },
            "buildSubmission" : {
              "href" : "http://localhost:8080/build-submissions/1"
            },
            "buildAndTestSubmission" : {
              "href" : "http://localhost:8080/build-submissions/1/buildAndTestSubmissionParent"
            }
          }
        }, ... ]
      },
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/build-submissions{?page,size,sort}",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "profile" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/build-submissions"
        },
        "search" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/build-submissions/search"
        }
      },
      "page" : {
        "size" : 20,
        "totalElements" : 5,
        "totalPages" : 1,
        "number" : 0
      }
    }
```

the build-and-submission and build-submission is a 1:1 relation ship.
My question is:

Most angular tutorial shows how to use httpclient to get a simple non-nested object using example like below:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:9000/build-and-test-submissions')
            .subscribe((response: any) => {
              let buildAndTests: any[] = response;



                this.products = response;
                this.onProductsChanged.next(this.products);
                resolve(response);
            }, reject);
    });
```

But how do I do http get for objects with relation? E.g. Shall I nest a http get of a build-and-test-submission object and a build-submission object?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would do a console.log(buildAndTests) to see the structure

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:9000/build-and-test-submissions')
        .subscribe((response: any) => {
          let buildAndTests: any[] = response;

           console.log( buildAndTests );
           console.log( buildAndTests._links.self.href );


            this.products = response;
            this.onProductsChanged.next(this.products);
            resolve(response);
        }, reject);
});
```

then you can start trying until you get what you need, for example if you evaluate

buildAndTests._links.self.href 
should return "http://localhost:8080/build-and-test-submissions/1"